# UI automation tool for Java Swing application with Record and Playback and screen capture facilities

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, ui-automation

Can someone suggest a UI automation tool for a Java Swing application with Record and Playback and screen capture facilities

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for tools on the free side, check out

Frankenstein - http://frankenstein.openqa.org/

Abbot and Costello - http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml

On the paid side, suites such as Rational Functional Tester are pretty powerful, though pretty complex.

Be sure to do as little testing possible with the record and playback (meaning extract your logic to the controllers/models and test those via automated unit/functional tests). Automated UI testing is very difficult and brittle and should really be done late in the project when your UI is no longer changing much.

Comment: Yes, The UI isn't going to change much. I am trying to use Costello. Not sure how to get the screen capture/ screen shots using Costello though.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that part about the screenshots. I'm not sure about that offhand, been a while since I've used that tool.

Comment: But it does have the screen capture option? It has capture component and capture reference

Comment: Does anybody still use Costello? It seems to initially work on my machine, but then it takes over 30 seconds to click a menu item.

Answer (score 3):

On the paid side you can also look at what Mercury has to offer : Winrunner is one of the 800-pound gorillas in UI testing.

I know of Abott : http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml

Another interesting project is [project Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/)

Comment: now Sikuli is called SikuliX: http://www.sikulix.com

Answer (score 0):

Marathon http://sourceforge.net/projects/marathonman/ is also a good tool for Java Swing testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at [ReTest](https://www.retest.de/en/). It's novel approach to functional regression testing is a new way to understand "screen capture" (which also includes screenshots, but a lot more than that). It combines this with ai-based monkey testing.

It is about to become open source as well.

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of the company behind ReTest.